# Can android apps send specially-crafted ARP packets?

Tags: android, arp

This is probably going to sound very dumb, because I'm fairly new to android development (it's basically just a hobby for me). Regardless, I was wondering: is it possible for my android app to send specially-crafted ARP packets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, a standard app can't do that. It would require a rooted device and giving the app required permissions.